# Css background linear Gradient direction from ( Left to Right )

Tags: html, css, gradient

```css
#myGrad {
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
}
```

```html
<div id="myGrad">howdy I am fun</div>
```

In this code, I want to use a gradient from left to right. How can I apply left to right gradient background?

Comment: Please also include the HTML you wish to apply this to.

Comment: I added a snippet with arbitrary HTML as an example but update it as you need

Answer (score 1):

You can use different methods to achieve that, for example adding this keyword: `to right`. [linear-gradient() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient())

```
#myGrad {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);
}
```

```css
#myGrad {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);
}
.myGrad{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myGrad" class="myGrad"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need only this property: `background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);` if you want to left change it to `...to left,...`

```css
#grad1 {
  height: 55px;
  background-color: red; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow);
}
div {
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
    color:#888888;
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight:bold;    
    height:500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grad1" class="">
From left to right
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of linear gradient is,
linear-gradient(direction, stop color 1 , stop color 2)

So you can write it as,

```css
#myGrad {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right,red, yellow);
}
```